# Ensuring Same date format in JSON objects

Tags: json, angular, oracle, postgresql

Setup :
Angular 8 + Spring boot 2.2.3 + (Oracle 12.1 / PostgreSQL 12.3)

We are building a approval System where User can fill online form like google forms and can submit for approval. Rather than normalizing form structure , we'll be storing metadata in JSON format in our DB.
Values that are filled in form would also be going as JSON format in DB.

One point come up as a concern , in DB we can store **date** in particular format like 12-May-2020 which would be consistent across all inserted data as this data might be used to construct reports in near future.

Based on pros/cons of this approach need to decide on DB / data model as well.

So,

- Is there any way I can enforce date format in JSON
- If this cannot be done in JSON , what options do i have at Angular 8 / Spring boot application level which would enforce all developers / date components / date fields to use same date format.
- If these cannot be done , how can I handle different formats in Query over JSON data that would be used in reporting or otherwise , both in Oracle and PostgreSQL

Regards

Comment: `12-May-2020` is not a "consistent"format - it would e.g. be invalid in any non-english speaking country. If at all a string formatted as `2020-05-12` would be "consistent". But if you need to make sure you are storing valid dates, then create a proper `DATE` column, don't put it into a JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution to your problem is to create a real, normalized `date` column.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to do that, I would create a check constraint that validates the date format by trying to cast it to a real date value.

The following is for Postgres, but you can create something similar for Oracle as well:

```
create table the_table
(
   form_data jsonb,
   constraint check_valid_date check ( (form_data ->> 'entry_date')::date is not null)
);
```

Obviously you will need to adjust the expression that gets the date value from the JSON to match the key and path inside your json value.

The cast to `date` will require that the date value is entered using the ISO standard format, `yyyy-mm-dd` which is the only "consistent" way to store a date as a string.

Alternatively you can use `to_date()` with a format mask:

```
check ( to_date(form_data ->> 'entry_date', 'yyyy-mm-dd) is not null)
```

Comment: Hi , ran this in postgreSQL . I was able to insert both the below records
========================================================
insert into the_table values ('{"entry_date" : "2020-05-05"}');
insert into the_table values ('{"entry_date" : "05-05-2019"}');

Comment: @Sid: probably because your locale settings allow 05-05-2019 as well. You could use `to_date()` with an explicit format mask (but do **not** use a format mask that uses month _names_). `yyyy-mm-dd` is the only sensible format to use there, as that is the only unambiguous one.

Comment: [1/2] Hi , your to_date() function in check works well for our need. DateStyle setting for my local DB is : ISO, MDY . Should this be changed to only ISO ?

Comment: [2/2] Date field name would differ across forms and would have names like REQUESTED_ON_DATE , APPROVED_ON_DATE , DIRECTOR_APPROVED_ON_DATE .. in check constraint , how do i accomodate all these names without having to run alter command for each new field that is added ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Sid: you will have to add a check constraint for each key. Or write a function that passes the JSON and a list of keys to check. You can avoid all that by normalizing your data model and storing the values in proper `DATE` columns

Comment: I was able to create function and make it work for my use case . But we'll be going ahead with normalized data for form values to avoid any future / unseen maintenance problems . Thanks for your advise and time .

Answer (score 0):

> in DB we can store date in particular format like 12-May-2020

You are mistaken, `Oracle` *doesn't store date in that format*. It is internally stored in `TYPE12/13` data type. Each bit represents different parts of the date. What you see is a human readable format displayed according to your **locale-specific NLS settings** or using `TO_CHAR` with format mask.

To keep it aligned across all platforms, use the globally accepted `ANSI standard date literal` which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

For example:

```
DATE '2020-05-21'
```